# Can we group the check box in html

Tags: html, forms, checkbox

I have a basic question about html.
I know when we are using radio button we can group several buttons by giving them the same "name" attribute, i.e. only one of them can be selected. e.g.:

```
<p> example
<input type="radio" name="example" value="option 1"> option 1
<input type="radio" name="example" value="option 2"> option 2
<input type="radio" name="example" value="option 3"> option 3</p>
```

So in the example, user can only choose one among option 1, option 2, option 3.
My question is whether we can do the same thing for checkbox ? Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. Checkboxes are meant to be selected independently. That's why both checkboxes and radio elements exist. It's not just for different appearance.

However, it's common approach to group checkboxes by name, using array-like convention:

```html
<input type="checkbox" name="example[]" value="option 1"> option 1
<input type="checkbox" name="example[]" value="option 2"> option 2
```

Form sent that way will be parsed by the server-side language as one array of checked elements.

Comment: How do we handle this array in controller ? For example, let's say we are in Java servlet, do we handle it like  String[] arr= request.getParameter(''example[]")? And the selected values will be the elements in the array?

Comment: I haven't used Java in a while, but I'm pretty sure you'd skip the brackets there. `request.getParameter("example")` should be enough.